# nodejs: Using child process in aws lambda to run python script not working

Tags: python, node.js, serverless-framework

Using the [serverless](https://serverless.com/framework/) framework and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826884/using-child-process-spawn-on-aws-lambda-for-a-python-script) post as guide I would like to print out some info from a python script, I have got this relevant code in my handler.js

```
const path = await require('path')
const { spawn } = await require('child_process')

/**
 * Run python script, pass in `-u` to not buffer console output 
 * @return {ChildProcess}
 */
runScript() {
    return spawn('python', [
        "-u",
        path.join(__dirname, 'script.py'),
        "--foo", "some value for foo",
    ]);
}
const subprocess = await runScript()

// print output of script
await subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`data:${data}`);
});
await subprocess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`error:${data}`);
});
await subprocess.stderr.on('close', () => {
    console.log("Closed");
});
```

and I also have `script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, getopt, time

def main(argv):
    argument = ''
    usage = 'usage: script.py -f <sometext>'

    # parse incoming arguments
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hf:",["foo="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print(usage)
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print(usage)
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-f", "--foo"):
            argument = arg

    # print output
    print("Start : %s" % time.ctime())
    time.sleep( 5 )
    print('Foo is')
    time.sleep( 5 )
    print(argument)
    print("End : %s" % time.ctime())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I am expecting my console to show output or an error when I invoke handler function but it prints nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
const path = require("path");
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const runScript = () => {
  return spawn("python", [
    "-u",
    path.join(__dirname, "script.py"),
    "--foo",
    "some value for foo"
  ]);
};

const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const subprocess = runScript();

  subprocess.stdout.on("data", data => {
    console.log(`data:${data}`);
  });

  subprocess.stderr.on("data", data => {
    console.log(`error:${data}`);
  });

  subprocess.on("close", code => {
    if (code !== 0) {
      reject(code);
    } else {
      resolve(code);
    }
  });
});

await promise;
```

No need to use `await` for synchronous functions, and by wrapping `subprocess` with a promise you can `await` on it.

Comment: Thanks that worked great! but I've tried returning `data` after 'subprocess.stdout.on("data", data => {' but instead it returns '0'

Comment: Can you please post your new code? Maybe in a new question. If you use `return data` inside the `stdout.on` callback it returns the data to the caller which is the `spawn` internal code. 

You can do

`let allData = '';  subprocess.stdout.on("data", data => { allData = allData + data.toString();  }); resolve({ code, allData });` or something similar